# How to handle permission check in React app (State maintain in Redux)?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

How to handle permission check in React?
I tried in two ways. Any better way to handle permission check or which one is most good to use?

**Type 1**
    Pass permissions via context. Permission component gets permissions from context if permission satisfy return component or null

```
class HomePage extends React.Component{
  getChildContext(){
   return {permission:this.props.permission}
  }
   render(){
     return <div>
       <Permission check='Edit'>
         <PopupMenu> 
           <div>Edit</div>
         </PopupMenu>
       </Permission>
       <Permission check='Delete'>
         <PopupMenu> 
            <div>Delete</div>
         </PopupMenu>
       </Permission>
   </div>
  }
}
HomePage.childContextType={permission:...}
class Permission extends React.Component{
    render(){
       if(this.context.permissions.indexOf(this.props.check)!=-1)
         return this.props.children
       else
         return null;
    }
}
```

**Type 2**
    Check the permission in the mapStateToProps function and return props based on permission

```
class HomePage extends React.Component{
    render(){
    return <div>
       <PopupMenu> 
          <div>{this.props.operation}</div>
       </PopupMenu>
    </div>
    }
  }
function mapStateToProps(state){
   var operation="";
   if(state.permission=="Edit"){
      operation="Edit"
   }
   else if(state.permission=="Delete"){
      operation="Delete"
   }
   return {operation}
}
connect(mapStateToProps)(HomePage)
```

Answer (score 0):

either solution is fine.  Note the 2nd solution offers various levels of access, while the first solution is "all or nothing".  So it just depends upon your needs and coding style preferences.

Comment: Thanks. Any other way? example